# Java Serialization with respect to different Contexts

Tags: java, serialization, json-serialization

I am little confused with respect to Serialization as to what it mean with respect to different contexts.

Serialization as I understand (simple terms) -> Converting the object to a form wherein it can be transferred to network / storage.

Now, i was reading JSON, and again concept of "Serialization" appeared; which said transforming Java Object -> JSON as Serialization; and vice-versa as Deserialization.

I am slightly confused at the applicability of Serialization / Deserialization with reference to different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Both technologies allow to serialize Java-objects to network/storage, but use different formats.

Java serialization produces a binary format, while JSON serialization produces JSON-Strings. The former one is faster but tied to Java, the later one ist slower but you can use it to exchange informations with systems not written in Java.

Comment: But in both cases, is Java which does the serialisation? I am not clear still :-(

Comment: Yes in both cases. If you want to use java serialization, you just call ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(). In case of JSON serialization you use some java-API - Jackson for example - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_(API).